# Using Jquery to replace text inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have something that looks like

```
<div id="ABCLinks"> : <span dir="ltr"><a href="www.google.com" title="GOOGLE">Google</a></span>
```

I am trying to replace only the text ":" with "Websites:" Without adding any source tags around it ().

This is what I have tried with no effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
​        $("#ABCLinks").text(function () {
            return $(this).text().replace(":", "Websites:"); 
        });​​​​​
    }); 
</script>
```

I am getting this html output (I am using a php skin to automatically embed my jquery script, it works for other jquery scripts)

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
&#8203;$("#ABCLinks").text(function () {
return $(this).text().replace(":", "Websites:"); });&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues,

1. Your selector is incorrect

   `​$("#ABCLinks")` is for referencing the ID field.
2. The HTML function would be a lot better for this

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString

`.html( htmlString )`

htmlString

Type: htmlString

A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  ​$("#ABCLinks").html("Websites:");
});​​​​​ 
</script>`

edit. And the fiddle for your particular circumstance: http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/7/

Comment: this kinda works. Except it removes: <span dir="ltr"><a href="www.google.com" title="GOOGLE">Google</a></span>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/7/

Comment: Im going to give you a kiss! Thank you so much! Works perfect!!!! That ones space between Websites and the ":" is making me a little OCD but i think i can live with it ;)

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark this solution as having answered your question! You also can probably get rid of that space by removing it from the start of the HTML - `<div id="ABCLinks">:&nbsp;<span dir="ltr"><a href="www.google.com" title="GOOGLE">Google</a></span>`

Comment: O yea sorry i was so excited I forgot to mark it as a solution ;)Unfortunately I cannot touch the html source to edit it because it is being generated from something else. That is why i am using a skin to embed these jquery scripts to edit all that random text i don't like! But i will live with it!!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ABCLinks").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace(":", "Websites:"); 
    });
});
```

You gave your div an ID, but tried to call it by class in jQuery.  Classes are referenced using a period like '.ABCLinks', while IDs are referenced using a hashtag like '#ABClinks'

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/

Comment: +1 ..You can just use the txt passed in as second argument. Why do you want to wrap a jQuery object inside it `text(function (_, txt) {
        return txt.replace(":", "Websites:"); 
    });`

Comment: Thank you AnthonyMasi, your solution works when i go to jsfiddle.net, BUT I am implementing this code in a php skin that will automatically place the script into my html files. I have used jquery before with this skin and i have had no problem. But for some reason my html source is getting screwed up and it won't accomplish the replace. I updated my post so you can see the weird output source I am getting....

Comment: #8203; is the unicode "zero width space" character.. is it affecting your script? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: Yes it is affecting my script, it won't implement the replace i want

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/

Comment: Look at the answer below! You don't need to do the replace at all, you can simply set the html of the div to "Websites:" -- http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/5/

Comment: Yea but it removes <span dir="ltr"><a href="www.google.com" title="GOOGLE">Google</a></span> and that link isn't the same for every page, so I can't just also include the link

Comment: Added below, but you can simply append the "Website" on the front of the <div> like so - http://jsfiddle.net/ERe9z/7/